# How to detect system background touch in android studio programmatically

Tags: java, android

I am building a Screensaver app. **The task of this app is: The app will run in the background and dims the screen to 0% after a certain period and when user touch from anywhere the screen brightness will back to 100%.**

The app is now running in the background. This app dims the screen brightness to 0% after a certain period also. I do these tasks by using Service. **But I can't detect the background screen touch in my app to dim the screen brightness back to 100%.**

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend your class with OnGestureListener, OnDoubleTapListener. Study OnGestureListener, OnDoubleTapListener from developer.android.com. Wish this will help you.

Comment: Does it work for the background system screen? I want to detect touch even the app is minimized.